# Extract URL params in ServiceStack VB.net

Tags: vb.net, web-services, jquery, servicestack

How to extract URL params in ServiceStack VB.net?

For example Query URL:

`http://localhost:3318/api/ActionName/?callback=cb&format=json&SomeParam1=19-11-2012&SomeParam2=123123`

Just FYI I am making a request with jQuery AJAX.

**Global.aspx**

```
Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication

    Public Class HelloAppHost
        Inherits AppHostBase

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New("Web Services", GetType(BiffaNetWebService).Assembly)
        End Sub

        Public Overrides Sub Configure(ByVal container As Container)
            Routes.Add(Of APIRequest)("/api").Add(Of APIRequest)("/api/{ActionName}")
        End Sub
    End Class

    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim apphost = New HelloAppHost()
        apphost.Init()
    End Sub

End Class
```

**WS.vb**

```
Public Class WebService
    Implements IService(Of APIRequest)

    Public Function Execute(ByVal request As APIRequest) As Object Implements ServiceStack.ServiceHost.IService(Of APIRequest).Execute

        Dim ActionName = request.ActionName
        Dim UserData = request.UserData

        // Do some stuff here and return JSON

    End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

If you inherit from `Service` in [ServiceStack's New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) or `ServiceBase(of T)` (if you want to keep using the Old API), you'll have access to `base.Request` and `base.Response` properties which you can use to get fine-grained access to HTTP APIs, e.g:

```
var someParam = base.Request.QueryString["SomeParam"];
```

Otherwise if you want to keep your services only implmenting the `IService` interface then you also need to implement `IRequiresRequestContext` which gets ServiceStack to inject the RequestContext for the request into your service. In this case you can access the QueryString with:

```
var httpReq = base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>();
```

var someParam = httpReq.QueryString["SomeParam"];